# What html flairs are available for Ask Ubuntu and Stack Exchange users in general?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, data

From time to time you may see a user flair on a user profile or embedd elsewhere. For instance here's mine:

[image: profile for Serg on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I learned about this flair thingy long time ago from fellow users (specifically, it was  @Fabby who introduced this to me), but today this got me thinking: are there any other types of flairs like this that show different types of data ? Perhaps "latest answer" or "Most voted questions of the user".

P.S: Excuse the use of "thingy", the "$USER" not well versed in HTML terminology.

Comment: You asked me when you were a wee little laddie and now you're a giant with > twice my rep.  **:-)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to clear things up, this is called "User Flair", and exists on the StackExchange network data for a user under the 'flair' tab, or accessible by specific URLs such as the site-specific one:

```
https://askubuntu.com/users/flair/10616.png
```

... which only shows the reputation on that specific site, or the StackExchange-wide one:

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/297701.png
```

(Both of these are mine, by the way)

User Flair such as that is not customizeable beyond the theme in use according to all the Meta.SE threads I checked for this.

Known themes to exist are (appended by `?theme=` to the PNG URL):

- None (the default)
- `dark` - makes a dark theme
- `clean` - can't tell the difference from default but it works
- `hotdog` - makes a lot of red.

I don't think you can customize this to have anything such as "latest answer" or "most voted questions" - at least, there isn't any such 'flair' that I have found for this.  I went hunting for such things and didn't find them.  If they exist, they aren't documented, though I highly doubt there's any type of 'custom' embed-able code that gets you the other stats.

(There may have been at one point, that was done via a third party service, but not anymore.)

---

And just to confirm I made inquiries via certain discreet channels, and got a "Yeah there's nothing other than user rep you can put there" as the reply.

Comment: Thanks , Thomas. Welp, that's slightly disappointing. Would nice to have a flair of the sort "What is the user up to lately" and embed this into a blog or github account. But oh, well.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Every user [has an RSS feed](https://i.imgur.com/w3HVp0D.png) (yours is [here](https://askubuntu.com/feeds/user/295286)) that contains some of the info you're looking for. So theoretically you could build your own flair that pulled from that RSS feed.

Comment: Just a note, that when using a specific site's URL instead of stackexchange.com for the user flair, it will show the reputation of that site only, and not the whole network.

Answer (score 6):

I host a customisable flair on my website. I wrote the code myself, and it is under the MIT licence. It's more involved than pasting an image into a webpage, but it is a higher quality end product, which is more customisable. It uses the API v 2.2 to get the data. You can change it however you want - move the parts around, chose your own font, change the background colour etc.

To get different information you would have to change the `filter` value to select the desired information - if people wanted this I'm sure I could add something to implement it!

You can [get it here](https://github.com/timtjtim/SEFlair), with usage instructions, or have a look at a live example on [my website here](https://timtjtim.co.uk/Flair/), and [see where I use it here](https://timtjtim.co.uk/OnlineAccounts/) (scroll down a little).

Examples:

[image]
[image]

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: You seem to have an encoding issue on your website, see the comment that contains a moderator icon in your javascript: `// If a user is a moderator, add the diamond â™¦ symbol`